# The cardinality of a language over a set of variables $V$ with $\#V= κ$

Tags: logic, cardinals, model-theory, first-order-logic, formal-languages

In predicate logic, to define a language, we consider the following $3$ sets:

(1) $V$, the set of variables;

(2) $F$, the sets of function symbols;

(3) $P$, the set of predicate symbols with their arities.

Now I am concidering about determine the cardinality of a language over a set with arbitary cardinality, $κ$(**Note that** $κ$ **can be either finite, countablely infinite or uncountablely infinite** ).

May I please ask:

If the cardinality of $V$, $\#V = κ$, what conditions on $V$ , $F$ and $P$ will give us a language over $V$, $F$ and $P$ with cardinality $κ$?

And may I please ask if it is the fact that if $\kappa$ is finite, then to get a language with cardinality $\kappa$ we need $(V+F+P)^{<\omega}=(\kappa+F+P)^{<\omega}=\kappa$, so we can never have a language of cardinality $\kappa$. I think it is something weird here. Am I wrong with something?

I had googled it but I have get nothing from websites, now I am confused. Could someone please help? Thanks so much!

**EDIT**: Latter I am told that in my course, the cardinality of a language refers to the set of **expression** instead of this of the set of **strings**. So now I need to consider further about when a string makes sense.

**EDIT'**:Now I am considering that if we can find out a general way to determine the cardinality of expression, which may related to combinatorics. See this question: [In general, how to determine the cardinality of the set of expression over a language?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266826/in-general-how-to-determine-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-expression-over-a-lan) Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Have you tried computing the cardinality of said language in function of the cardinality of $V$, $P$, $F$ ?

Comment: @Max I know that maybe it is somehow related to the cardinality of the function set $F$ or the set $F_M$ when intepreted in the model. But I do not know where exactly should I go forward to.

Comment: @Max In fact, I fell stuck on applying the model theory properly in the question.

Comment: Re: your second-to-last paragraph, see my edits. No language (in the sense of the question) can be finite unless it is empty.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, I have just had a look and see it. Thanks a lot for your patience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\kappa=0$, then the language is empty if there are no nullary function symbols (= constant symbols), and otherwise has nonzero (hence $\not=\kappa$) size. If $\kappa\ge 1$ but $\kappa$ is finite, then the language is infinite (no nonempty language in the sense of the question is finite) and hence it is not of size $\kappa$.

So all that's left is $\kappa$ infinite, and it turns out that the issue of (un)countability is irrelevant here. Each formula in the language is a finite string built out of symbols from $V, F, P$, and the logical symbols (of which there are finitely many). Since $V$ is infinite, the cardinality of the set of formulas is thus $(V+F+P)^{<\omega}$.

Now clearly if $F$ or $P$ has size $>\kappa$, we can't have the language have size $\kappa$. Meanwhile, for infinite $\kappa $, $(3\kappa)^{<\omega}=\kappa $. So the language has size $\kappa$ exactly when F and P have size at most $k $.

Comment: Sorry for the fact that I cannot understand it completely. May I please ask if it works for uncountable infinite $k$? I forgot to mention it and now I have edited the question. If it works, may I please ask for some further explainition to let me see why?

Comment: @PropositionX It works for **all $\kappa$** (assuming a very weak version of the axiom of choice). I've edited to give more details.

Comment: Thanks! May I please ask if the notation "the $<\omega$ th power" means the cardinality of the set of strings of any finite length? Does $(V+F+P)^{<\omega}$ denotes the cardinality of the union of the sets of strings of each length $n\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: @PropositionX Yes, that's right.

Comment: I have asked which is the cardinality refers to. And in my course, the cardinality of a language is refers to the cardinality of the set of all expressions instead of the set of all finite strings.Knowing about this definition I am doing further consideration... So knowing these about the set of strings, may I please ask further for what can we know about the set of expressions?

Comment: If possible, could you please have a look and talk about the general case here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266826/in-general-how-to-determine-the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-expression-over-a-lan

Answer (score 1):

If $\Sigma$ is an alphabet of infinite cardinality, then the language $\Sigma^\star$ of finite strings over $\Sigma$ has the same cardinality as $\Sigma$.